# Plesk / Pin domain to the same home directory as another domain

Tags: linux, centos, plesk

is it possible to pin domain to another's domain **home directory**?

Example: I have domain1.com and domain2.com. Now I want domain2.com pin to **same** **home directory** as domain1.com to access the same files.

I don't want Alias Domain, because it's just redirecting doman2 to domain1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your goal will result in issues/errors/problems, due to the fact, that each domain will create it's very own domain - specific system-user, who owns files/folders, when you use Plesk. The domain - specific system-user from domain2 will not be able to interact with the content of domain1.